# How to web scrape meta content - Python web scraping question

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to only scrape the word "Automobile" not the entire line with the meta brackets.

Desired output: "Automobile"

Can you please tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/13/skoda-reveals-uk-pricing-for-enyaq-coupe-iv-vrs/'

(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
category2 = soup.find('meta', property='article:section')
print(category2)
```

Output:

```
<meta content="Automobile" property="article:section"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `['content']` to your `soup` object.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.electrive.com/2022/02/13/skoda-reveals-uk-pricing-for-enyaq-coupe-iv-vrs/'

(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
category2 = soup.find('meta', property='article:section')['content']
print(category2)
```

Output:

```
Automobile
```